# Exception during pool initialization

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

I'm creating a spring boot project. Then i try to connect mysql database to that project. I got the error called "HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization".

This is the whole stacktrace.

```
2020-07-10 23:37:36.630 ERROR 14824 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'unknown' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the 'serverTimezone' configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:73) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:76) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:197) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477) [HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:560) [HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) [HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) [HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:158) [spring-jdbc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:116) [spring-jdbc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:79) [spring-jdbc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:324) [spring-jdbc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.isEmbedded(EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.java:120) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateDefaultDdlAutoProvider.getDefaultDdlAuto(HibernateDefaultDdlAutoProvider.java:42) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration.lambda$getVendorProperties$1(HibernateJpaConfiguration.java:130) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateSettings.getDdlAuto(HibernateSettings.java:41) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.determineDdlAuto(HibernateProperties.java:136) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.getAdditionalProperties(HibernateProperties.java:102) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.determineHibernateProperties(HibernateProperties.java:94) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration.getVendorProperties(HibernateJpaConfiguration.java:132) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.entityManagerFactory(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:133) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:635) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1109) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at com.example.demo.CrudApplication.main(CrudApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.InvalidConnectionAttributeException: The server time zone value 'unknown' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the 'serverTimezone' configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:85) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.mysql.cj.util.TimeUtil.getCanonicalTimezone(TimeUtil.java:132) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.configureTimezone(NativeProtocol.java:2120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.initServerSession(NativeProtocol.java:2143) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:1310) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:967) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:826) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    ... 54 common frames omitted
```

Comment: can u please check my answer. I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

One way is specify the server time zone in the jdbc connection url as:

```
jdbc:mysql://xxxxx:3306?serverTimezone=UTC
```

(You can use other timezones too)

Another way is to set the timezone property in the mysql server. Follow the documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time-zone-support.html)

If you are deploying your mysql in azure:

set the server parameter time_zone to particular zone.

Follow the doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/howto-server-parameters#setting-the-global-level-time-zone)